# Edit files in /etc/profile.d and /usr/local/bin through Windows in Bash on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Bash on Windows and I want to put some files in `/etc/profile.d` and `/usr/local/bin` through Windows.

I noticed there's no `etc` or `usr` in `AppData\Local\lxss` and creating such folders have no effect in Bash.

There is however `etc\profile.d` and `usr\local\bin` in `lxss\rootfs` but again, adding any of my own files in them has no effect in Bash either. They don't even show up:

[image]

I basically my set of frequently used `/etc/profile.d` scripts and and `/usr/local/bin` binaries that I want to install on any Linux environment.

How or where do I put these scripts and binaries so that they show up in `/etc/profile.d` and `/usr/local/bin` in Bash on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible it seems. As mentioned on this page: [Windows Subsystem for Linux Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)

> Two file systems are used to provide access to files on the users system: VolFs and DriveFs.
>
> **VolFs** provides full support for Linux file system features [...]
> Directories containing the Linux system, application files (/etc, /bin, /usr, etc.), and users Linux home folder, all use VolFs.
> Interoperability between Windows applications and files in VolFs is ***not supported***.

Which has exactly been my experience so far. Anything I try to change in `/etc` or `/usr` from `AppData\Local\lxss` or `lxss\rootfs` does not go well. The only changes I make that do show up as expected in Bash are in the mounted volumes. Because...

> **DriveFs** is [...] used for interoperability. All fixed Windows volumes are mounted under /mnt/c, /mnt/d, etc., using DriveFs. This allows users to edit files with their favorite Windows editors such as Visual Studio Code, and manipulate them with open source tools in Bash using WSL at the same time.